# Is it possible to create an IP address radix in modelsim?

Tags: modelsim

Is there anyway to make ip address words display in the decimal dotted format in the waves window?

Comment: Verilog or VHDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inclined to think the answer is no, because that would require combining a non string value (each portion of the Ip) with a string literal (the period). The best option is to ask modelsim.

However, there is an option that might make things easier.  If you have  your IP as a 32 bit numerical value (vector or unsigned or equivalent) there is a way to split the value into 4 custom vectors of 8 by selecting the 8 bits and selecting tools -> combine signals.